# forceChatter:feed lightning component actions comment, share, edit buttons not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Greetings and thanks for the read/advice!

Have a very basic application:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c.MyAPP_TopicFeed/>
</aura:application>
```

with a lightning component that looks like this:

```
<aura:component >
<div aura:id="feedContainer" class="feed-container">
    <forceChatter:feed type="Topics" subjectId="0TOC00000008eVX" />
</div>
```

Please note the subjectId is hardcoded to a valid topic in my org..

This component displays the following when rendered but the buttons and functions - comment, share, and edit features are not functional.

[image]

When I inspect the source and look at the action it appears that these methods are doing anything..  javascript:void(0)

```
<a title="Comment" href="javascript:void(0)" class="cuf-commentTrigger drillInTarget slds-post__footer-action">
<svg class=" slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon--x-small slds-align-middle ">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/_slds/icons/v7.18.0/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#share_post"></use>
</svg>
 Comment
</a>
```

Anyone know why this doesn't work and moreover how to make this standard component functional?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is broken is because some of the events and functionality listen for events inside lightning frame .

Hence you will need to use app builder and create a page and add this component to get it functional .

You can test this without adding in lightning app builder or the community builder .

Comment: Thanks Mohith! Sorry I am a bit confused by your answer.  You speak about a lightning frame but doesn't a lightning application run within the context of a lightning frame?  Trying to create a salesforce1 application and am debugging this using developer console preview.  ( do not wish to use the app or community builder ) .. Are you saying this component is only supported in those context and not for a standard lightning component rendered via app?  >> i.e. https://mycustomdomain.lightning.force.com/c/MyAPP_TopicFeedApp.app

Thanks!!

Comment: thats correct ! Run inside an app builder or create a lightning tab with this component .

Comment: Gotcha.. appears both the forceChatter:feed and forceChatter:publisher have the following conditions "The feed component is supported for Lightning Experience and communities based on the Customer Service template."  

That leaves us with only forceChatter:fullFeed which 'The fullFeed component is still considered BETA and as such shouldn't be considered ready for production.'  :(

Comment: Yes and did you see now they have a pilot program for the chatter:connect .I think you should contact sfdc and get access to pilot .It provides integration capability inside the chatter.

Comment: Thanks Mohith for your for your insightful answers!! Are you implying to use the chatter connect API to make REST calls and manually roll my own chatter feed component?  Or does some other pilot feature exist..  Sorry I only can find reference to API..  Imagine it will be pretty important for organizations to drop chatter feeds into lightning components in the future and do not believe rolling my own would be a good investment..

Comment: @BenjaminPirih check this one https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_integrate_customapps_to_publisher.htm

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using forceChatter:Feed, you can use forceChatter:fullFeed. This will resolve your issue.

component code

```html
<div aura:id="feedContainer" class="feed-container">

    <forceChatter:fullFeed />
       
</div>
```

Js code

```javascript
   $A.createComponent(
        "forceChatter:fullFeed", {
            "type": "Record",
            "subjectId": component.get('v.strCountry')
        },
        function(recordFeed) {
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (component.isValid()) {
              
                var feedContainer = component.find("feedContainer");
                feedContainer.set("v.body", recordFeed);
            }
        });
```